# If a function's domain is an empty set, how can its derivative still exist graphically?

Tags: functions, derivatives, graphing-functions

I read in my textbook that if we add two functions (with domain $D_1$ and $D_2$), the domain of resulting function is $\displaystyle{D_1 \cap D_2}$.

Now, if we add $f(x)=\ln(1-x)$ and $ g(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}$. The domain of $p(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ is an empty set, so there is "no graph" for this function $p(x)$. How to interpret this?

However, if I take the derivative of this function, I obtain a graph. How is this possible? The function itself did not exist, but we have a slope(derivative) for that function which is represented graphically?

Comment: then how to express?

Comment: The derivative of $\log(1-x)$ is $\frac{1}{x-1},$ which is also the derivative of $\log(x-1).$ So, while $\log(1-x)$ cannot be extended to $x>1$ in the obvious way, you can extend it as $\ln(|1-x|).$

Comment: Both the functions are differentiable in different domains, hence while their sum appears to be differentiable, it actually isn't.

Comment: Your *derivative* is presumably something like $- \frac{1}{1-x} -\frac{1}{2(1-x)^{3/2}}$.  This is not real for $x \le 1$, while for $x>1$ it is in fact the derivative of functions of the form $\ln(x-1)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}+c$, which does not include your $f(x)+g(x)$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I read in my textbook that if we add two functions(with domain d1
> and d2) the domain of resulting function is the intersection of d1
> and d2.

Yes, you cannot add numbers that don't exist. So, for $f(x)+g(x)$ to be defined, you need both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to be defined, which means that $x$ is in $d_1=dom(f)$ and in $d_2=dom(g)$. Therefore, the domain of $f+g$ is $d_1\cap d_2=dom(f)\cap dom(g)$.

> Now if we add $f(x)=\ln(1−x)$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x−1}}$, the domain of $p(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ is a null set.

Yes, since $dom(f)=(-\infty,1)$ and $dom(g)=[1,\infty)$, their intersection is empty, so the domain of $p$ is empty.

> But if I take derivative of this function, I get a graph.$

If a function is differentiable at $a$, then it is defined at $a$ (by definition of the derivative). By contraposition, since there is no number $a$
where $p$ is differentiable, then $p$ is not differentiable.

Note that the derivative of $f(x)=\ln(1-x)$ is $f'(x)=\frac{-1}{1-x}$ with $dom(f')=(-\infty, 1)$, not $dom(f')=\mathbb R\setminus \{ 1 \}$.

Comment: The last sentence of this answer explains the OP's confusion. The formula for the derivative happens to make sense where the function is not defined - but it is not the derivative of the nonexistent function there.

Answer (score 6):

This answer is in the context of real analysis.

> $f(x)=\ln(1-x)$ and $ g(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}$. The domain of $p(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ is an empty set, so there is "no graph" for this function $p(x)$. How to interpret this?

The function $p$ has an empty domain, so has an empty image, so has "no graph".

> However, if I take the derivative of this function, I obtain a graph.

Actually, Desmos returns an [empty graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hz1mqekxaw) for $p'.$

As $p$ is defined nowhere on $\mathbb R,$ it has a derivative nowhere on $\mathbb R;$ that is, $\boldsymbol{p'}$ **has an empty domain**, regardless of the fact that **it has a mapping rule** $$x \mapsto -\frac1{2 {(x - 1)}^{\frac32}}- \frac1{1 - x}$$ **that applies nowhere**.

---

**Addendum**

> $p'$ actually has a graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ti0zlsilix (the black one)

In my previous paragraph, the word "defined" is important: we know that the function $p'$ has an empty domain by derivation from how you have *defined* $p$ as the sum of $f$ and $g.$

When you got Desmos to graph that mapping rule, it is natural for Desmos to do so with its natural domain (its maximal domain). Referring to your black curve as function $q:$ we say that $\boldsymbol {p'}$ **is a restriction of** $\boldsymbol q.$

P.S. I shall be preachy: technology is a tool, not a substitute for thinking, judgement and volition.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kdtubmjjnv  this has both the f(x) and f'(x) graph see for yourself and please explain how f'(x) has a graph?

Comment: @Harshavardhanan I've boldfaced the explanation so that you cannot miss it. Click on the link again, and notice that $p'$ actually has an empty graph. To be clear: a function isn't just about its 'rule' but also its domain. Your previous question has a similar answer: you are wrongly treating two functions with different domains as the same just because they share the same 'rule'.

Comment: p' actually has a graph please look in the link:https://www.desmos.com/calculator/j3gbrb43xm the blue curve

Comment: @Harshavardhanan  Yes I already saw that graph; and responded with my previous comment; you seem to be intently ignoring the boldfaced explanation too. $\quad$ If I say that you are a zillionaire in every city that has a unicorn, then am I suggesting that you are a zillionaire in NYC? What good is that mapping rule for $p'$ if it is applicable nowhere?

Comment: but can you please explain why when I differentiate it myself and put it in desmos it shows a different graph? (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ti0zlsilix) (the black one) is p'(x).

Comment: @Harshavardhanan You persistently claim that that graph is $p'$ even though I keep pointing out that **a function isn't just about its 'rule' about also its domain** and that that graph does **not** have an empty domain which $p'$ does. $\quad$ Desmos and chatGPT are both tools that you don't use blindly; when you ask Desmos to plot a graph by giving it a function rule, how is Desmos to know that *your* required function has an empty domain? $\quad$ Please read more thoughtfully and less selectively.

Answer (score -1):

In this particularity, the domain of the derivate should follow anti-derivate function. Ie. $\big( \ln{(1-x)} \big)' = \dfrac{-1}{1-x}, x < 1$. While, on its own, $\dfrac{-1}{1-x}$, has the domain $x \in \mathbb{R}  \backslash \{1\}$, in the question it is specifically bounded as the derivate of another function, so consider it as "child"(output) which follows its parent domain. Think of the reverse, $\displaystyle{\int{\dfrac{-1}{1-x}} = \ln|1-x| + c}$. Now, $\dfrac{-1}{1-x}$ is the "parent" and, hence the output, $\ln|1-x|$, must follow the domain of the integrand (input).

Edit: I figure to say that the derivative in your question should not take on values that were never in the domain of the antiderivative, otherwise the it would defy the antiderivative itself. One needs to be consistent with the domain of **original function** where the question begins.

Comment: Not my downvote, but "The output function should exist at all values where the input would, otherwise it is not the correct, derivate/anti-derivative" is incorrect.  Not all functions are differentiable everywhere on their domain.

Comment: @L.F. thats true.